# How could I simplify this command to only use awk?

Tags: command-line, shell, sed, text-processing, awk

```
awk '/user/ {print $1 }' /etc/userdomains | sed 's/://'
```

the format of /etc/userdomains is

```
domain.tld: user
otherdomain.tld: otheruser
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the field separator to ":"

```
awk -F":" '$2~/user/{print $1}' /etc/userdomains

And if you want to check for exact username, 

awk -F"[ \t]*:[ \t]*" '$2=="user"{print $1}' /etc/userdomains
```

Comment: What's the $2~ part about?

Comment: @kizzx2: A bare `/user/` is like `$0 ~ /user/` – `$2 ~ /user/` means "does `$2` match `/user/`"?  Also, if the string `user` can vary depending on input, be sure to use `-v` to avoid having to deal with quoting issues, e.g. `awk -v "user=$USER" '$2==user{print$1}'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` in `awk` to remove all `:`s in the string.

```
awk '/user/ {gsub(":", ""); print $1}' /etc/userdomains
```

Comment: no need to use the extra brackets in `/(user)/` . Just `/user/` will do

Comment: @user: Right, no idea how those got there.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` has a `sub(regexp, replacement, target)` function that finds the first occurrence of `regexp` in `target` (`$0` by default) and replaces it with `replacement` (in-place):

```
awk '/user/ {sub(/:/, ""); print $1}' /etc/userdomains
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tr` instead of sed:

`awk '/user/ {print $1 }' /etc/userdomains | tr -d ":"`

Though I don't see how that's better than just using awk (nor do I see what's wrong with sed).

Comment: There's no point using `tr`, since i believe OP wants to get rid of extra commands. Just one awk command does the job.

Comment: yeah it's more of a what's the point of piping to sed when awk can do it all, and in this case I believe is more effective than sed. corrected my question to be more straightforward on that.